# App that uses cloud storage provider

Tags: google-drive-api, dropbox-api, onedrive, data-synchronization, cloud-storage

I'm in the middle of designing an app that will help manage your life better. I personally like having control of my data. So instead of storing everyone's database on a server that I provide,

I want the user to use their own personal storage through providers like google drive, dropbox, onedrive, etc. The reason for this so that an android app, ios app, desktop app, web app, etc can all be in sync if the database was pointed to that storage provider.

I would like to know a few things if any of you have experience with this:

1. What would be wrong using this design for storage? Greater chance for apps to be out of sync? Slow performance? Chance of corruption if user messes with database directory?
2. I couldn't find any articles of an app that uses this method. Does anyone know of any articles on the web or your own personal words on how to go about implementing this?

I would like to hear your thoughts on this and reccomendations.